# Odoo show values of selected Many2one record

Tags: orm, model, view, odoo

In my custom view, there is a field Many2one, next to it I would like to show values of that item as information in view after a serial_number is selected.

```
# model.py (newApi)
serial_number = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="stock.production.lot", string="Serial Number", required=True)

# view.xml
<field name="serial_number" options="{'no_open': True, 'no_create': 1, 'no_create_edit': 1}"/>
    <div>
        <span>serial_number.product_id.name</span>
        <span>serial_number.product_id.description</span>
    </div>
```

How I have to do correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you need to use *widget='selection'* This will make *many2one* field as a selection field.

try with this:

```
<field name="serial_number" widget='selection'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

USE related to do this :
Create a related fild in the model that have many2one relation 
like this

```
field_name = fields.Char(string="Selected value", related="Field_name_in_co_model")
```

than put it in your form with readOnly :

```
<field name="field_name" readonly="1" />
```

when the user select an item the information of the selected record will show automaticly in the fields sorry for my english if you didn't undertand tell me i will give an exemple 
you can even put it in tree form it's greate thing